# Implementando Skype ao site

Tags: javascript, html, api, http, skype

Estou testando o recurso do skype WebControl, onde é possivel adicionar uma janela de chat do skype no site. Porém eu estou com alguns erros que não estou conseguindo resolver. A janela em si aparece, mas aparece erros no console e não consigo enviar as mensagens.

No site eu adicionei essas duas linhas de codigo:

```
<span class="skype-button bubble" data-color="#00AFF0" data-text="#80DDFF" data-contact-id="williantartaro"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

Pensei que seria as requisições em https, porem coloquei em site teste com o mesmo e deu igual: https://apps.streeteyesapp.com/mmp/teste.xhtml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]